# Using opencv in python to find the second largest contour by area and it's inner contours

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am looking for a way to find the inner contours of the second largest contour found from an edge detected image.

I am able to return the second largest contour by area, but cannot work out how to separately return the child contours of the second largest contour. I also wish to exclude the contours within these inner contours, i.e. return all of the child contours but none of the grandchild contours.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Test 01.jpg',1)
img_padded = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[0,0,0])
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img_padded,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(imgray, 30, 200)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations = 1)


_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

second_largest_cont = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[1:2]

#Sec_large_child_cont = ?

draw = cv2.drawContours(img_padded, second_largest_cont, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
#draw_inner = cv2.drawContours(img_padded, sec_large_child_cont, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('Draw', draw)
#cv2.imshow('Draw Inner', draw_inner)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Apologies if this is super simple, I am quite new to programming.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please study this wonderful article on [Contour Hierarchy](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Comment: How about the latest version of OpenCV to do this kind of job? Please show me.